# In C++ struct, what is the difference between default value and default argument in constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

for a struct Foo; What is the difference in terms of performance, memory operations, etc between

```
struct Foo {
 int foo = 1;
};
```

vs

```
struct Foo {
Foo(int haha = 1) : foo(haha) {}
int foo;
};
```

Which is preferred to be used?

Comment: These are two different things. One defaults it to `1`, the other allows you to set it to whatever you want. An equivalent version would be `Foo(int haha = 1)`, or by having a secondary `Foo() : foo(1) { }` version.

Comment: First one is only available since C++11 and is an aggregate (since C++14).

Comment: Yeah thanks sorry I mean the Foo(int haha = 1) : foo(haha) {} on the second case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no true difference.

Every modern compiler (e.g., GCC, Clang, MSVC) will optimize away any difference between the two. For instance, this code:

```
struct Foo {
    int foo = 1;
};

struct Bar {
    int bar;
    Bar(int value = 2) : bar(value) {}
};

void test() {
    auto f = Foo();
    auto b = Bar();
    keep(b);
}
```

will be compiled to this by GCC with the lowest level optimization (-O1):

```
test():
        mov     eax, 1  // auto f = Foo();
        mov     eax, 2  // auto b = Bar();
        ret
```

([Source](https://godbolt.org/z/4pEoiO))

So in both cases, the entire constructor call is optimized away, ending up with a single instruction for each. (Results may vary, but generally the same is the case for each compiler.) There's no performance gain going one way or the other.

---

My point with this is that there's not really any point in doing this kind level of manual optimization unless you're *extremely* short on resources, since the compiler is almost always smarter than you and can optimize these things for speed/memory better than you can do by hand.

Instead, you should make your choice based on what you think is the clearest code. That's the only think that makes a true difference here.

Comment: There actually is a difference between the two - if I have default values but no constructors, I can still use [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) to construct objects of that class (this applies in C++14 and C++17).

Comment: This is significant because if a class contains resources (like a std::unique_ptr or std::vector or some other container) aggregate initialization can be more efficient than having an explicit constructor by forcing the compiler to elide moves of prvalues.

Comment: In addition, aggregate initialization can be used to initialize classes with member variables that *can't* be copied or moved.

Answer (score 0):

It largely depends on your compiler.  I put your code into CompilerExplorer and this is what I found:   https://godbolt.org/z/5WmOno

They're very similar but the first way is more efficient.  In the case of `int foo = 1;` the value is used directly in the constructor.  In the other case, the value is put on the stack by the caller of the constructor even though it is a default value.